# Adding Javascript Object inside existing JSON Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Apologies if this seems obvious, but I've been lost on it for a few hours now.

I'm attempting to create a javascript object and pass it to a PHP page using JQuery's .ajax.

The JS object looks like:

```
let transactions = {};
let counter = 0;
($.each loop) {
    transactions[counter] = {
        "code": code,
        "agency_number": agency_number,
        "agency_code": agency_code
    };
    counter++;
}
```

I then need to add it, along with another field to a JSON array

```
let formData =  [{}];
    formData.push({name: 'page', value: aPage});
    formData.push({name: "transactions", value: JSON.stringify(transactions)});
```

The AJAX Call like:

```
let ajax_call=$.ajax({
                datatype: "json",
                method: "POST",
                url: "theURL",
                data: formData,
                timeout: 15000,
                async: true
            });
            ajax_call.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
               ... blah ...
```

wrapping transactions in JSON.stringify doesn't seem to work. On the PHP end, the POST value for transaction looks like:

```
"{0:{CODE:300,AGENCY_NUMBER:20,AGENCY_CODE:50}}"
```

No ticks, which doesn't allow me to use json_decode. It outputs "syntax error" as expected.

passing it just as transactions, without the JSON.stringify yields the result:

```
formData.push({name: "transactions", value: transactions});

=

"[OBJECT OBJECT]"
```

which is a string representation of that, not an actual object to work with.

I'm not doing anything with the POST values up until this point. This is how the PHP page is receiving them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit - There wasn't actually anything wrong with the code here. I was restricting quotation marks, along with other special characters, from hitting the web server in IIS. That's why it was coming through without them. All is well, I am just dumb.

Thank you all for the assistance otherwise.

Comment: If can I ask, what happen if you apply JSON.stringify over formData object (after add 'transactions') ?

Comment: @ÁngelB.It's escaping the quotes around the transaction object's data. Which that seems to be why the first result is happening. Looks like the default content type header for .ajax may be doing this?

Comment: Just an hint: there's no need to call the .done() method on your ajax object, you can use the success parameter inside the configuration, like this:
```$.ajax({/*...*/ success: function(result) { console.log(result);  // this will print the response in the console once the ajax call is done with success });```

you can define ```error``` to handle a bad response from the server (like for Http error code 500 Server error, or 401 Unauthorized, etc..), with ```complete``` you can define a function that will be executed in any case when the call is complete, regardless  of it response type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery ajax.data can accept regular JS objects. You don't have to create name:value pairs and stringify anything.

This should work better:

```
const formData = {
    page: aPage,
    transactions: []
};

($.each loop) {
    formData.transactions.push({
        "code": code,
        "agency_number": agency_number,
        "agency_code": agency_code
    })
}
```

Comment: Your approach seems much cleaner. Thank you!


As a side note, I was restricting quotation marks in IIS, which is why it was coming through without them in my POST. Everything here was correct (aside for efficiency improvement 8) ), I am just stupid.

Marking your answer correct, because there wasn't actually anything wrong in the post and I appreciate your advice :)